# Handling with two warnings of @ARGS

Tags: perl

Small debug question I can't solve for some reason. Consider the following code:

```
use warnings;
my $flag = 0;
foreach my $i (0..scalar(@ARGV)) {
    $data{$OPTION} .= $ARGV[$i]." " if($flag);
    $flag = 1 if($ARGV[$i] =~ /$OPTION/);
    undef $ARGV[$i] if($flag);
}
```

I get the following two warnings:

```
Use of uninitialized value within @ARGV in concatenation (.) or string at line 4
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at line 5
```

I get the reason is that I undefine some value of `@ARGV` and then it tries to check it.

The way I do it like this is because I would like to 'cut' some of the data of `@ARGV` before using `GetOpt` module (which uses this array).

How to solve it?

Comment: @TTaJTa4 Please always post a [mcve], that way you will get answer that address the problems of the code you show, not the code you hide from us.

Comment: @TTaJTa4  Re "_didn't include all the script_" -- (1) please do include enough; this isn't clear (2) Still, `0..scalar @ARGV` is off-by-one as @toolic says; you need `0..$#ARGV` (to iterate up to the last index, not up to array size!).  (Btw, you wouldn't need `scalar` there anyway)

Comment: Why not `use Getopt::Long;` instead of manually processing `@ARGV`?

Comment: If you undef an element of @ARGV, how is that going to help `Getopt`?? Did you consider that it might well confuse it?  I'd suggest, show us a brief example of what you want to do.

Comment: switching to `0..$#ARGV` solves it :). is the scalar necessarily?

Comment: Well, `$#ARGV` is a scalar, a number: the last value of index. So no need for `scalar`.  What I meant above is that if you stick `@ary` in a scalar context, what the range operator `..` imposes, you still don't need `scalar`; so `0..@ary` will count from 0 to the size-of-array.  Incidentally, you practically never need this: if iterating over indices you want to stop at the last index, which is array-size - 1, not array size.

Answer (score 3):

Let's expand on those comments a bit.

Imagine `@ARGV` contains four elements. They will have the indexes 0, 1, 2 and 3 (as arrays in Perl are zero-based).

And your loop looks like this:

```
foreach my $i (0..scalar(@ARGV)) {
```

You want to visit each element in `@ARGV`, so you use the range operator (`..`) to generate a list of all those indexes. But `scalar @ARGV` returns the number of elements in `@ARGV` and that's 4. So your range is 0 .. 4. And there's no value at `$ARGV[4]` - so you get an "undefined value" warning (as you're trying to read past the end of an array).

A better way to do this is to use `$#ARGV` instead of `scalar @ARGV`. For every array variable in Perl (say `@foo`) you also get a variable (called `$#foo`) which contains the last index number in the array. In our case, that's 3 and your range (`0 .. $#ARGV`) now contains the integers 0 .. 3 and you no longer try to read past the end of the array and you don't get the "undefined value" warnings.

There's one other improvement I would suggest. Inside your loop, you only ever use `$i` to access an element from `@ARGV`. It's only used in expressions like `$ARGV[$i]`. In this case, it's probably better to skip the middle man and to iterate across the elements in the array, not the indexes.

I mean you can write your code like this:

```
foreach my $arg (@ARGV) {
    $data{$OPTION} .= $arg . " " if($flag);
    $flag = 1 if($arg =~ /$OPTION/);
    undef $arg if($flag);
}
```

I think that's a little easier to follow.